# Get all available attributes with values for special collection on EAV

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance, entity-attribute-value

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-attributes) for deploying EAV model.

As any EAV system I have different table for storing varchar, boolean, text and integer value in my database, and attributes table for storing attribute.
I need to get all available attribute based on my posts list (collection).

For example a special list of posts

```
$posts = Post::where('category_id',2)->where('tag_id',4)->get();
```

On each post I have difference attribute with difference value, I need a way to get all attribute on this list (not all attribute on system) AND available value based on this collection.

I'm developing a filtering page for my posts and I need to show available attribute on sidebar with their available value to change.

Comment: 3 tables -- that add complexity to an already complex design pattern (EAV).  Condolences.

Comment: @RickJames , I posted my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE - Solution**

Finlay I found a good solution for getting all attributes based on my query.

```
   $attributes = $posts
        ->leftJoin('attribute_boolean_values', 'attribute_boolean_values.entity_id', 'posts.id')
        ->leftJoin('attribute_varchar_values', 'attribute_varchar_values.entity_id', 'posts.id')
        ->join('attributes', function ($join) {
            $join->oron('attribute_boolean_values.attribute_id', 'attributes.id');
            $join->oron('attribute_varchar_values.attribute_id', 'attributes.id');
        })
        ->groupBy('attributes.id')
        ->select([
            'attributes.slug as slug',
            'attributes.type as type',
            'attributes.id as id',
        ])
        ->get();
```